# Unable to float a twitter bootstrap navbar item right with either class=pull-right or float:right

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, formatting, firebug

I am using Twitter bootstrap and Rails and I can't seem to float a navbar item to the right.

I tried using something like this:

```
<li class="whoami pull-right"> <%= link_to ("Logged in as: " + current_user.name), edit_user_registration_path , :id=>"Edit account"%> </li>
```

... but the link stayed left and firebug showed `"float:left;"`

So I tried to overide the css float in `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` and in `home.html.erb`, but neither worked.  Firebug indicated that it found two css float statements, but chose the bootstrap option over mine. So I am left stuck and wondering how to customize the navbar.  I am probably doing something wrong here, but I just don't see it.

Here's my code:

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  ... removed to shorten the length of this post
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
          <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    </header>
    <div id="main" role="main">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
              <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
              <%= yield %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <footer>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div> <!--! end of .container -->
    </div> <!--! end of #main -->
  </body>
</html>
```

_navigation.html.erb:

```
<div class="container span12">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav">
        <%= link_to "Cases", root_path, :class=>"brand"%>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
              <li> <%= link_to "My Cases", cases_path %> </li> 
              <li> <%= link_to 'Dash', dash_path %> </li> 
            <% if current_user.has_role? :admin %>
              <li> <%= link_to 'Admin', users_path, :id=>"Admin" %> </li>
            <% end %>
            <li> <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete', :id => "Logout" %> </li>
            <li class="whoami"> <%= link_to ("Logged in as: " + current_user.name), edit_user_registration_path , :id=>"Edit account"%> </li>
          <% else %>
              <li> <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %> </li>
              <li> <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %> </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
body { 
    padding-top: 60px;
}
@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";

// Set the correct sprite paths
// ...REMOVED to shorten the length of this post
// Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
//
// Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
// you may use and inherit here
//
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html for their names and documentation
//
// Example:
// @linkColor: #ff0000;

.whoami {
    float:right;
}
```

When I load a page, I see the navbar, but the last item is not floated to the right.

Looks like this:
[image: Screen capture showing firebug info]

And there is another screen cap here that shows [some more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqTBQ.jpg).

As you can see, firebug found a `"float:right;"` option, but indicates a `"float:left;"` option was used instead.

I have a gap in understanding here, but I am not sure where.

Please address responses to:

- Use of pull-right and twitter bootstrap navbar formatting
- Overriding css
- Interpreting firebug output

  EDIT:
  I've posted my first ever jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uCHQs/2/
  It represents a copy/paste of a browser 'show source' and what I gather is the relevent css load and served by rails.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Got it.

Getting it to work required filling the container nested in navbar-inner with more than one unordered list of nav elements.  This jsfiddle showed me the way http://jsfiddle.net/N6vGZ/4/

This code works:

```
<div class="container span12">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "Cases", root_path, :class=>"brand"%>
          <ul class="nav">
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
              <li> <%= link_to "My Cases", cases_path %> </li> 
              <li> <%= link_to 'Dash', dash_path %> </li> 
            <% if current_user.has_role? :admin %>
              <li> <%= link_to 'Admin', users_path, :id=>"Admin" %> </li>
            <% end %>
            <li> <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete', :id => "Logout" %> </li>
          </ul>
           <ul class="nav pull-right"> <li> <%= link_to ("Logged in as: " + current_user.name), edit_user_registration_path , :id=>"Edit account"%> </li></ul>
          <% else %>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li> <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %> </li>
              <li> <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %> </li>
            </ul>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had the same problem with the navbar-search. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 3):

have you tried being more specific with your CSS?

```
.navbar ul.nav li.whoami {
    float:right;
}
```

Sometimes if the prior CSS (bootstrap in this case) is very specific, it requires the same level of specificity (or greater) to override it.

Might be helpful to post a jsfiddle. Screenshots are difficult to debug ;)

Comment: Well, that indeed lets me override and firebug shows float:right.  The browser still lays the navbar our with the item not-floated-right.  I'd be happy to post a jsfiddle, but am not sure how to copy what seems like a lot of js, css, and html from multiple paths.  Is there a nifty rails-way to do that?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I arrived at the answer above.  I'd characterize my issue as one of "my poor understanding of how a CSS developer thinks."  Now that I look at the working code, I wonder why it took me so long and the css layout makes a lot more sense.  Thanks for cluing me in to jsfiddle too.

Answer (score 1):

The code u have written is

```
 class="nav navbar-nav" col-12
```

The above code can be replaced like this

```
class="nav navbar-nav col-12"
```

and also at next insert

```
class pull-right in your li button
```

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the line

//...REMOVED

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I actually removed a block of already commented-out code there to shorten my (lengthy) post.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="#examples"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="float:right;"></span> Examples</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add new class = "row"

what's happened ..in your code . when it is coming in mobile device then div is append on other div .
this is simple solution .