# How do I post a jsfiddle example of some trouble I'm seeing in Rails?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, jsfiddle

This may be a very basic question, but is it possible to post a jsfiddle that captures a Rails environment, the js, css, and HTML that is generating a nagging problem?  I posted another SO question here:  [Unable to float a twitter bootstrap navbar item right with either class=pull-right or float:right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992493/unable-to-float-a-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-item-right-with-either-class-pull-rig)

... and it was suggested I post something to jsfiddle.  Honestly, I'm just completely in the dark as to how I might gather the css, js, and HTML in a way that can be copy-pasted into jsfiddle.  Is there some slick way to pull the 4 necessary components together?

I am mostly interested in being being able to share and debug code that pertains to display and layout.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The jsfiddle site is a workbench for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. It's not a server environment you can control; strictly a client-side thing, in other words. Thus you'll have to figure out what the client-side code looks like, which you should be able to do via a browser debugger or at least "view source".

Comment: Thanks Pointy.  Rails serves up a number of 'assets' which might be js files, css, images, and more. The served js is represented something like <script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>  when I 'show source.'  I can get a cocatenated list of the js using firebug, but I am not sure where to get a similar all-in-one-page listing for the css.

Comment: My interest is really in being able to share and debug code related to layout by the client.  I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Well it may help initially to play with the page using Firebug or the Chrome developer tools, so that you can see exactly what the CSS rules are that apply to the element you're having problems with.

Comment: Pointy, not that you need the rep, but if you post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as such.

Comment: OK answer posted. There are probably a couple of other similar questions out there but it's probably a good thing to have an easy-to-find question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sites like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) are useful as testbeds for various issues involving HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  A good workflow for using them might be as follows:

1. Before going to one of those sites, use a browser debugger (Firebug, the Chrome debugger, or even the debugger in modern versions of IE if you must) to figure out the mechanics of the issue. Are you seeing unexpected JavaScript behavior? Weird layout?  Whatever the problem, see if you can narrow the focus as much as possible.
2. Now, go to one of the workbench sites (make an account for yourself too; it helps to be able to find old experiments) and start trying to reproduce the problem. Start as simply as possible and work up. It can be hard and frustrating, but in my experience even the process of trying to figure out an isolating test case can itself lead to enlightenment :-)
3. If you do manage to isolate a behavior that you don't understand or can't explain or whatever, you can then save the test case (jsfiddle has "Save" and "Update" buttons; jsbin seems to magically save things automatically) and then post the URL here (or anyplace else).  If you do post here, it's a good idea to copy the relevant code from your test case directly into your question.

I use both of those sites (and there may be more of them out there).  The jsbin site gives you a little more control over your page, and provides a way to see your page outside of an `<iframe>`.  That's kind-of important if you're testing for mobile applications.  Otherwise they're both great resources.

Oh, and both sites let you import various popular libraries via simple configuration tools.  That's really handy for tracking bugs that you think may have been introduced by a library version change (rare, but really freaky when it happens).